# Anaconda-Jupyter Doesn't open in browser

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

I installed Anaconda 3.7 on [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver). Installation was successful. When I tried to start Jupyter Notebook from navigator it throws the following error.

> Access to the file was denied The file at
>   file:///run/user/1000/jupyter/nbserver-26395-open.html is not
>   readable. It may have been removed, moved or file permissions may be
>   preventing access.

Comment: Please show how you are starting the Jupyter Notebook

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have changed your default browser from Firefox to something else, Jupyter Notebook works fine on Firefox but throws permission denied on Chromium (for me). Just go to Setting > Details > Default Application and select FireFox in Web. Cheers

Comment: I can open it just fine in Firefox, but I'd like to be able to open it in Chromium.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 23):

For me, this worked on Raspberry Pi4, Ubuntu 20.04, with Chromium Browser.

Generate the config file with following command.

`jupyter notebook --generate-config`

Config file is created at `~/.jupyter` directory

Look for parameter `c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file` and set the same as `False`.

`c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file = False` in order to disable launching browser by redirect file .

Explanation:

> For versions of notebook > 5.7.2, a security feature measure was added
>   that prevented the authentication token used to launch the browser
>   from being visible. This feature makes it difficult for other users on
>   a multi-user system from running code in your Jupyter session as you. 
>   However, some environments (like Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and
>   Chromebooks), launching a browser using a redirect file can lead the
>   browser failing to load.  This is because of the difference in file
>   structures/paths between the runtime and  the browser.

Also make sure the `~/.local/share/jupyter` and `~/.jupyter` directories are owned by the user running jupyter

Comment: This is the correct answer. See https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4500

Comment: Did not work for me but +1 for using RPI4

Comment: Did not work for Anaconda 2022.10, py39_0, anaconda-navigator 2.3.2 on Popos20.4

Comment: @mccurcio please make sure you have given permissions to ~/.local/share/jupyter and ~/.jupyter directories with your username

Comment: there is not such a parameter in my config fie

Answer (score 3):

[image: Ckick the link your terminal]

As shown in the image, jupyter notebook also provides a link. Try opening it with the browser of your choice. It worked for me...

Answer (score 2):

With recent versions of snap, applications installed with snap can't by default open files in hidden folders (with a name starting by `.`).

In Ubuntu 20.04, chromium is installed with snap (even when using the command `sudo apt install chromium-browser`), so chromium can't open the html file used by Jupyter.

As stated by @rahul-sood, a simple workaround is to copy-paste one of the alternative links given by Jupyter in the terminal (starting by `http://localhost:8889/?token=` or `http://127.0.0.1:8889/?token=`).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in open jupyterlab or jupyter notebook in chrome : install it in the terminal with

> sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable

It didn't work for me by using chromium. And, as mentionned paugier, in Ubuntu 20.04, chromium is installed with snap (even when using the command sudo apt install chromium-browser), so chromium can't open the html file used by Jupyter. So if you install chrome by using the terminal it works.

Answer (score 0):

Open Chrome and paste the Jupiter file path. In my case it's file:///home/vanx/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-14511-open.html and it worked.